# Как выбрать случайное число из трех (используя временный массив)?

Tags: массивы, delphi, случайные-числа, delphi-xe

Из трёх одномерных массивов, разного размера, получаю рандомно 3 разных числа:

```
array_01[Random(45)];
array_02[Random(5)];
array_03[Random(140)];
```

Далее хочу из этих трёх чисел получить ещё один рандом. Как быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сохраните эти числа в ещё один временный массив из трёх элементов и возьмите оттуда рандомный элемент:

```
var
  array_04: array [0..2] of something;

...

array_04[0] := array_01[Random(45)];
array_04[1] := array_02[Random(5)];
array_04[2] := array_03[Random(140)];

rnd := array_04[Random(Length(array_04))];
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз думал про однострочный массив из трёх чисел, но вот с его заполнением не сообразил.

Comment: Т.к. "Random returns a random number within the range 0 <= X < Range", то нужно `Random(3)`, а лучше, наверное, `Random(Length(array_04))`;

Comment: @kami Спасибо, исправил ответ.

Comment: @I_CaR если ответ является решением, отметьте его галочкой.